# How to do Ember integration testing for route transitions?

Tags: ember.js, tdd, integration-testing, ember-testing

I'm having a problem doing integration testing with ember using Toran Billup's [TDD guide](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/07/21/Integration-testing-your-emberjs-app-with-QUnit-and-Karma/).

I'm using Karma as my test runner with Qunit and Phantom JS.

I'm sure half of if has to do with my beginner's knowledge of the Ember runloop. My question is 2 parts:

1) How do I wrap a vist() test into the run loop properly?

2) How can I test for transitions? The index route ('/') should transition into a resource route called 'projects.index'.

```
module("Projects Integration Test:", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test('Index Route Page', function(){
    expect(1);
    App.reset();    
        visit("/").then(function(){
            ok(exists("*"), "Found HTML");
        });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: What version of ember are you using? I failed to mention a critical bug in RC 6 that breaks when you visit the "/" route https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2997

Comment: Ah! I'm using R6.1! Sorry, I forgot to mention in my question. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just pushed up an example application that does a simple transition when you hit the "/" route using ember.js RC5

https://github.com/toranb/ember-testing-example

The simple "hello world" example looks like this

1.) the template you get redirected to during the transition

```
<table>
{{#each person in controller}}
<tr>
  <td class="name">{{person.fullName}}</td>
  <td><input type="submit" class="delete" value="delete" {{action deletePerson person}} /></td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

2.) the ember.js application code

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("other", { path: "/" });
    this.resource("people", { path: "/people" });
});

App.OtherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('people');
    }
});

App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Person.find();
    }
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
});

App.Person.reopenClass({
    people: [],
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/api/people', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(hash) {
                var person = App.Person.create(hash);
                Ember.run(self.people, self.people.pushObject, person);
            });
        }, this);
        return this.people;
    }
});
```

3.) the integration test looks like this

```
module('integration tests', {
    setup: function() {
        App.reset();
        App.Person.people = [];
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $.mockjaxClear();
    }
});

test('ajax response with 2 people yields table with 2 rows', function() {
    var json = [{firstName: "x", lastName: "y"}, {firstName: "h", lastName: "z"}];
    stubEndpointForHttpRequest('/api/people', json);
    visit("/").then(function() {
        var rows = find("table tr").length;
        equal(rows, 2, rows);
    });
});
```

4.) the integration helper I use on most of my ember.js projects

```
document.write('<div id="foo"><div id="ember-testing"></div></div>');

Ember.testing = true;

App.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

function exists(selector) {
    return !!find(selector).length;
}

function stubEndpointForHttpRequest(url, json) {
    $.mockjax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        responseText: json
    });
}

$.mockjaxSettings.logging = false;
$.mockjaxSettings.responseTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm unfamiliar with Karma, but the portions of your test that needs to interact with ember should be pushed into the run loop (as you were mentioning)

```
Ember.run.next(function(){
  //do somethin
  transition stuff here etc
});
```

To check the current route you can steal information out of the ember out, here's some information I stole from stack overflow at some point.

```
var router = App.__container__.lookup("router:main"); //get the main router
var currentHandlerInfos = router.router.currentHandlerInfos; //get all handlers
var activeHandler = currentHandlerInfos[currentHandlerInfos.length - 1]; // get active handler
var activeRoute = activeHandler.handler; // active route
```

If you start doing controller testing, I wrote up some info on that http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/unit-testing-multiple-controllers-in-emberjs/1865

Comment: Ember.run.next() did get my test to run without an error, but I'm getting a Fail message stating that there were no assertions? I love the example above about tapping into the current route to get current info on handlers. I'll definitely play around with that in my testing!